# Probability questions: choose n from r

Tags: probability

At the end of a semester,29 students in a statistics class rated their instructor on a five-point scale (i.e., evaluating him/her as very poor, poor, fair, good, and excellent). How many different ratings combinations are possible?

I thought the answer was 5^29. But the answer showed the following:

Suppose that arrange the five-point scale in a straight line as follows
|0 − −|1 − −|2 − −|3 − −|4 − −|5
To the left of each we may place the students who choose that particular
evaluation
(5)|0 (2)|1 (5)|2 (6)|3 (5)|4 (6)|5
So we have 5 students who chose 0,2 students who chose 1,5 students who
chose 2,6 students who chose 3,5 students who chose 5 and 6 students who chose 5.
Look at the problem in the following way: there are a total of 5 − 1 + 29
boxes spaces to be filled either with the markers or with the students. We
discount the last marker |5 because it is in only space with no individual after
it. We now need to choose 5-1=4 boxes in which to place the markers and
this can be done in (5-1+29 chose 4) = 40920 ways

Comment: That depends on whether you keep track of which student rated the professor what amount.  Typically these are done anonymously so that there can be no fear of retaliation.  As such, a rating sequence of poor,poor,poor,excellent,... is considered the same as a rating sequence of excellent,poor,poor,poor,... so long as the total quantity of each matches.

Comment: To be fair, the way the question was written was poor and did not mention this.